# Xpath expression returning only several (not all) hits

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath

I am trying to write a small R script to scrape real estate pricing data from a Polish website: [www.otodom.pl](http://www.otodom.pl)

I am trying to build a data frame with basic information: ad title, price, price per square meter, size etc.

Each page has 36 entries by default, but my Xpath expression only returns 6 of them. I have inspected the class setup and the class details seem consistent throughout the website.

The precise URL I am using is:

```
https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferty/sprzedaz/mieszkanie/krakow?distanceRadius=0&page=1&limit=36&by=DEFAULT&direction=DESC&viewType=listing
```

I am trying to pull all ad titles by using the Xpath expression:

```
//h3[@class='css-qch36y e1n6ljqa6']/text()
```

Why is this only returning 6 results instead of 36?

I get 6 results both using R Studio and in the XPath Playground: https://scrapinghub.github.io/xpath-playground/

Answer (score 1):

With the following code, I get 39 houses on the web page. It is possible that the approach that you consider does not load the page completely before you get the "H3 titles".

```
library(RSelenium)

url <- "https://www.otodom.pl/pl/oferty/sprzedaz/mieszkanie/krakow?distanceRadius=0&page=1&limit=36&by=DEFAULT&direction=DESC&viewType=listing"
shell('docker run -d -p 4446:4444 selenium/standalone-firefox')
remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4446L, browserName = "firefox")
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(url)

web_Obj <- remDr$findElement("id", "onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
web_Obj$clickElement()

web_Obj_House <- remDr$findElements("xpath", "//h3[@class='css-qch36y e1n6ljqa6']")
web_Obj_House[[1]]$getElementText()
[[1]]
[1] "6-Pokojowe - 103 MKW - TARAS z widokiem na park"

web_Obj_House[[39]]$getElementText()
[[1]]
[1] "Słoneczne 2 Pokoje_ Bezpośrednio_Duży Rabat"

length(web_Obj_House)
39
```

Comment: Thanks! I wonder how our two approaches are different really. We use the same xpath expression after all. Why would one approach load the entire site and the other not. You can tell I'm not an expert at this...

Comment: Maybe the approach you are using does not load all the page before checking for the "H3". So, since only a part of the page is loaded when you check for the "H3", then you only get 6 results. It would be useful to have the code of your approach. It would help to explain the differences between your approach and my approach.